# Поворот элемента на графической сцене (QGraphicScene)

Tags: c++, qt

Есть у меня на сцене объект – карточка с двумя сторонами и текстовые элементы на ней.

Карта находится в горизонтальной ориентации (она же альбомная).
Понадобилось разворачивать карту в вертикальную ориентацию, так чтобы часть элементов оставались на своих места и разворачивались с картой, а другая часть перемещалась относительно нового верхнего левого угла. На скриншотах понятнее будет.

Текущая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется чтобы можно было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минимальный проект с проблемой: https://github.com/gil9red/card_design_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы элементы по флагу поворачивались с картой (назовем их зафиксированными) или располагались на ней с учетом расположения на нового верхнего угла карты нужно было сделать:

- Все элементы располагать на сцене
- Размещение всех элементов происходит вручную
- Для зафиксированных элементов поворот выполняется вручную

Карту поворачивал так:

```
// Поворот всей карты
QPointF center = card->boundingRect().center();
QTransform transform;

if (checked) {
    transform.translate(center.x(), center.y())
             .rotate(-90)
             .translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

} else {
    transform.translate(center.x(), center.y())
             .rotate(90)
             .translate(-center.x(), -center.y());
}
card->setTransform(transform, true);

card->isLandscape = !checked;

needRotate = true;
on_actionFill_triggered();
```

Размещение элементов на карте выполняется вручную с учетом того с какой стороне карты находится элемент и является ли он зафиксированным:

```
for (TextElement* item: items) {
    QPointF pos(item->_x, item->_y);
    CardSide* side = item->isFrontSide ? card->frontSide : card->backSide;

    if (!item->isFixedPos) {
        // Альбомная ориентация
        if (card->isLandscape) {
            pos = side->pos() + pos;

        // Портретная ориентация
        } else {
            QPointF posSide = card->mapToScene(side->pos() + side->boundingRect().topRight());
            pos = posSide + pos;
        }

    } else {
        // Поворот зафиксированного элемента
        QTransform transform;

        // временный костыль
        if (needRotate)
        if (!card->isLandscape) {
            transform.rotate(-90);
        } else {
            transform.rotate(90);
        }
        item->setTransform(transform, true);

        if (card->isLandscape) {
            pos = side->pos() + pos;

        } else {
            QPointF posSide = card->mapToScene(side->pos());
            pos = QPointF(posSide.x() + pos.y(), posSide.y() - pos.x());
        }
    }

    item->setPos(pos);
}
```

[Тестовый проект](https://github.com/gil9red/card_design_test).

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется если вы на объекте card сделаете layout и положите на него свои элементы TextElement, то они будут вращаться вместе с картой, когда вы делаете .rotate(-90). Или сделаете cadr parent_ом для TextElement_ов.
Должно сработаться. Сам не проверял...

Comment: Так то оно так, но нужно иметь возможность менять флаг у элемента, после которого он либо поворачивается с картой, либо занимает новую позицию (как на второй скрине). Вот тут у меня и не получается.